# modification to distribution, what's allowed?

Tags: custom-distributions, license

I plan to distribute a web application/database commercially via a VM image, (a virtual appliance). The plan is to use Ubuntu as the OS for this VM. I understand that we cannot modify the distribution without violating IP Rights and licensing rules.

Based on #2, 3rd bullet in the IP Rights Policy (http://www.canonical.com/intellectual-property-policy)

My question is: Does removing packages and stripping down the distribution constitute modification? Furthermore, does adding other components such as apache tomcat or posgreSQL DB constitute a "modification".

I tend to think not, but would like to hear from the community.